# I want to know why my FuelManager class is not recognized in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, dialogflow-es, fuel

[image]
The above part is me trying to use the FuelManager class that I have implemented.

These are my implementations in my gradle file.
[image]

I am trying to make a dialogflow chat in my android app. I have followed this tutorial, https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-conversational-interface-for-android-with-dialogflow--cms-30845, but I seem to lose my way through the tutorial. I'm a beginner and I am not to used to using android studio and kotlin itself, please help. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in [the docs](https://github.com/kittinunf/fuel/tree/master/fuel-android) Fuel's android package does not comes packed with the core package

Add the core package to your build.gradle file, and get the latest version 2.2.2 of both the library:

```
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel:2.2.2'
implementation 'com.github.kittinunf.fuel:fuel-android:2.2.2'
```